# Template class for class hierarchy?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to define a template class that can be used only with derived classes from a particular class hierarchy?

Say I have Animal base class

```
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual ~Animal();
        virtual void shout() = 0;
    };
```

and Dog, Cat,Tiger are derived classes

```
class Dog : public Animal{
    public:
    virtual void shout(){
        cout<<"Bark";
    }
}
class Cat : public Animal{
    public:
    virtual void shout()
    {
        cout<<"Meow";
    }
}
```

I need to define a template class say 'AnimalTemplate' that can be used ONLY with the derived  class of Animal, so if I try to do 'AnimalTemplate< Duck >', I should get compilation error( or some error ), even if Duck has a method shout() defined in it. 
(This question is mainly for me to understanding if we can mix OO paradigm with Generic programming)

Comment: Wait, aren't ducks animals too?

Comment: For this discussion lets say that ducks are not animals and they get shout() from a different base class say Bird. :)

Comment: Are you using c++11? If so, you could use [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: Ironically, templates provide duck typing. You are trying to strip it down to behave like a plain object oriented design.

Answer (score 4):

Two forms of this immediately come to mind:

**SFINAE**

```
template<typename T, 
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Animal,T>::value>::type>
class AnimalTemplate
{
public:
    AnimalTemplate() {}
};
```

**static_assert**

```
template<typename T>
class AnimalTemplate
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Animal,T>::value, "T must be derived from Animal");
    AnimalTemplate() {}
};
```

The latter is friendlier in telling you why it failed, obviously.

Comment: For completeness, tag dispatching of specializations?

Comment: @Yakk yeah, I should probably add it, just thinking of some creative names (for some reason Looney Toonz characters are leaping to mind).

Answer (score 2):

You can simple define your template in such a way that it uses the template argument as an `Animal`. For example:

```
template <typename T,
          bool = sizeof(*static_cast<Animal**>(0) = static_cast<T*>(0))>
class AnimalTemplate
{
    // whatever
};
```

Producing an error in case a template argument doesn't match is generally fairly trivial. If there is any method which is always instantiated, e.g., the destructor, that could be a palce where the check could go, too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding the code and explanation following it. Can you please explain a bit more? ( Apologies if this is something very common in generic programming world )

Comment: OK, the idea was to use an implicit conversion from `T*` to `Animal*` which exists only if `T` publicly derives from `Animal` (using the `static_casts()` I had originally actually also converts from base or `void*` to derived). The implicit conversion above is put into a `sizeof()` expression to make sure it isn't evaluate.

Comment: The `bool` argument itself is actually not used: the code there is simply meant to fail when the `T` argument isn't suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If `animalTemplate` is a *function* template you could just do:

```
template<typename T> void animalTemplate(T animal_candidate){
   auto& animal= static_cast<Animal&>(animal_candidate);
   animal.shout();
}
```

Most often templates trust the user to use the correct input. This is known as duck typing. (suiting for your case!) There is work for future C++ on defining *Concepts*, which may be used to specify what kind of input a template can take.